# MySQL backup/restore with master/master replication

Tags: mysql

I didn't find useful information in documentation that is why I decided to ask.

My environment is as this: Two MySQL servers with Master <-> Mater replication (let's call it Node1 and Node2).

All applications (99%) connects to Node1, on Node2 only one application which is doing `INSERTS` in a separate DB.

So - changes are propagated to both nodes because of replication. Also because of replication I have relay-bin-logs and bin-logs (on both servers).

I take backup on Node2 using `mysqldump`

QUESTION:

- in case of restore what I need to apply to DB?
- only "relay-bin-logs"?
- only "bin-logs"?
- both?
- What is the sequence?

(link to documentation is also appreciated)

Thanks!

P.S. In case of simple MySQL server (without replication) everything is pretty simple - restore from backup and after this apply bin-logs.

Comment: In response to your request for more information.
Walkthroughs and how-tos are available on Percona's performance blog, for example, https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/07/18/backups-and-disaster-recovery/ and its accompanying webinar. These are FREE resources and the software provided by Percona is also open source and entirely free. You may find Percona XtraBackup interesting, which works for MySQL and MariaDB as well as Percona Server for MySQL. https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup
-- disclosure I work for Percona

Comment: I do not work for Percona but I am also very satisfied with Percona XtraBackup - it creates consistent backup of data files - here is for inspiration small script we use - http://mysql.freeideas.cz/subdom/mysql/2017/08/30/bash-script-create-backup-with-percona-xtrabackup/
XtraBackup "prepare" automatically applies all bin logs created during backup. So for restoration you only replace data files no need for any long running restoration of dump files - see for inspiration: http://mysql.freeideas.cz/subdom/mysql/2017/09/08/restore-non-replica-from-data-files-backuped-with-percona-xtrabackup/